# Elementary Matrix Embedding

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

> Let $B'$ and $D'$ be $m \times n$ matrices, and let $B$ and $D$ be $(m+1) \times (n+1)$ matrices defined by 
>   $$B=\left[\begin{array}{c |cc}
>   1 & \begin{array}{ccc}0 & \cdots & 0\end{array} \\
> \hline
>   \begin{array}{c}0\\ \vdots\\0\end{array} & B' \\
> \end{array}\right]$$
>   and
>   $$D=\left[\begin{array}{c |cc}
>   1 & \begin{array}{ccc}0 & \cdots & 0\end{array} \\
> \hline
>   \begin{array}{c}0\\ \vdots\\0\end{array} & D' \\
> \end{array}\right]$$
>   Prove that if $B'$ can be transformed into $D'$ by an elementary row operation, then $B$ can be transformed into $D$ by an elementary row operation.

Since $B'$ can be transformed into $D'$ by an elementary row operation, there exists an $E' = [E_{ij}'] \in M_{n \times n}$ such that $D'=E'B'$. Now define $E=[E_{ij}]$ with $E'$ embedded in it as $B'$ is embedded in $B$, so that 
$$E_{ij} = \begin{cases} 1, & i=j=1 \\ 0, & i=1 \mbox{ or } j=1 \mbox{ but } i,j \neq 1 \\ E_{ij}', & i=1 \mbox{ and } j=2,3...,n \mbox{ or } i=2,3,...,n \mbox{ and } j=1 \end{cases}$$

The entries of $B$ and $D$ are defined similarly. Now we compute $(EB)_{ij}$. If $i=j=1$, then $(EB)_{ij} = \sum_{k=1}^{n} E_{1k} B_{k1} = E_{11} B_{11} + \sum_{k=2}^{n} E_{1k} B_{k1} = 1$. If $i=1$ and $j \neq 1$, then $E_{ik} = 0$ for every $k$ and so $(EB)_{ij} = \sum_{k=1}^n 0 \cdot B_{kj}=0$; the same is true for $j=1$ and $i \neq 1$. Finally...

Hmm...On second thought, I don't think I defined $E$ correctly; I am not sure how to fix the third definition. It's clear that $EB =D$, but hopefully someone can help me fix this third definition, or perhaps show me an easier way to prove that $EB=D$.

Sadly, this isn't the only trouble I am facing: I am trying to prove that $E$ is in fact an elementary matrix. I tried induction, but couldn't figure out how to use the induction hypothesis. For the base case, we have 
$$E = \begin{bmatrix} 1 & 0 \\ 0 & E_{11} \\ \end{bmatrix},$$
where $[E_{11}]$ is a $1 \times 1$ elementary matrix,  and multiplying the 2nd row by $\frac{1}{E_{11}}$ gives us $I_2$, thereby showing $E$ is elementary. The vacuity of the base case is unsettling, but perhaps it shouldn't be.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$E_{ij} = \begin{cases} 1, & i=j=1 \\ 0, & i=1 \mbox{ or } j=1 \mbox{ but } (i,j) \neq (1,1) \\ E_{i-1,j-1}', &i > 1 \text{ and } j>1 \end{cases}$$

If $E'$ corresponds to switching $i$-th and $j$-th row, $E$ corresponds to switching $(i+1)$-th row and $(j+1)$ row.

Try to find the corresponding operations for the other row operations.